# Model creation for User User collanborative filtering

Tags: model, mahout, collaborative-filtering, mahout-recommender

I want to do a sort of user-user collaborative filtering wherein the users in the user-item matrix are a selected part of whole users in the database. These selected users are refreshed regularly with newly selected users preferences. New users shouldn't be added to the matrix. For a new user, based on his preferences we need to recommend items from the user-item matrix (which has only a part of users which are selected). I do not want to add the new anonymous users to the matrix.

Explored in Mahout, but need some help there.
   The Recommender Class in Mahout has recommend(...)  method which takes the user_id as argument. This is not which I want. The method should accept the preferences and based on the model , items should be recommended. How to do it in Mahout?? Can we use PlusAnonymousUserDataModel ??

If not mahout, what other tools can accomplish this...

The code which I used with PlusAnonymousUserDataModel which is not giving any recommendations for the user who has recommendations with normal usage..

```
    DataModel model = new GenericBooleanPrefDataModel( GenericBooleanPrefDataModel.toDataMap( new FileDataModel(f)));
    TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity similarity = new TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity(model);
    UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood(1000, similarity, model);
    new_user_preferences = { ... } // new user items..
    DataModel plusmodel = new PlusAnonymousUserDataModel(model);
    PreferenceArray anonymousPrefs = new GenericUserPreferenceArray(new_user_preference.length);
    anonymousPrefs.setUserID(0, PlusAnonymousUserDataModel.TEMP_USER_ID);
    for(int i = 0;i < new_user_preference.length;i++)
    {
      anonymousPrefs.setItemID(i, new_user_preference[i]);
    }
    PlusAnonymousUserDataModel plusAnonymousModel = (PlusAnonymousUserDataModel) plusmodel;
    Recommender recommender1 = new GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, similarity);
    plusAnonymousModel.setTempPrefs(anonymousPrefs);
    List<RecommendedItem> recommendations1 = recommender1.recommend(plusAnonymousModel.TEMP_USER_ID, 10);
```

Is there any problem with the code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sravan_kumar, if you replace `model` with `plusAnonymousModel` in 3 places:
TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity similarity = new TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity(plusAnonymousModel);
  UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood(1000, similarity, plusAnonymousModel);
    Recommender recommender1 = new GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender(plusAnonymousModel, neighborhood, similarity);

and initialize plusAnonymousModel right, just after initializing model:
PlusAnonymousUserDataModel plusAnonymousModel = new PlusAnonymousUserDataModel(model);
(there is no need in plusmodel variable, as you use it)
, you will get the desired results!

Also, change `GenericUserPreferenceArray` to `BooleanUserPreferenceArray` :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `PlusAnonymousUserDataModel` is the closest thing to what you want in Mahout. It's a bit of a band-aid, but works.

Comment: Can multiple threads access the recommender at the same time if we use PlusAnonymousUserDataModel??

Comment: It's thread-safe, but there's an additional subclass of it designed for what you say.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Can you please elaborate the sub classes and how to use it.. Will the PlusAnonymousUserDataModel class modify the matrix with new user's preference??

Comment: And also can I be able to scale to around 10million users with aroud 1million items accessing the recommender systems using PlusAnonymousUserDataModel??

Comment: I tried to use PlusAnonymousUserDataModel .. I took a user from the training data itself and with normal recommender, able to get recommendations. But with PlusAnonymousUserDataModel for the same user I am not getting any recommendation.. Please help. I am adding the code to the question..